# Want to add pushbutton to setTimer and setText

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, signals-slots, data-distribution-service

I am newbie in GUI design. Here, in sending and receiving messages (float, integer values) using DDS (OpenSplice) I am trying to add a pushButton to my already existing labels(displaying some float values as shown below), so that after a clicking on the pushButton, I should be able to see data in my label.
I tried adding a push button with the help of Qt Network sender Example. Now I get the error *undefined reference to 'MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() in the file moc_mainwindow.cpp* while building the project.

**fastsender.cpp**

```
FastSender::FastSender(QLabel *x, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
wSend = x;
dataTimer = new QTimer(this);
emergency = new QPushButton(tr("Emergency"));
buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox;
buttonBox->addButton(emergency,QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);


connect(emergency, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startsending()));
connect(dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(walk()));
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);
}

void FastSender::startsending()
{
emergency->setEnabled(false);
dataTimer->start(100); // Interval 0 means to refresh as fast as possible
}


int FastSender::walk()
{
msg->value= i+0.1;
snprintf (buf, MAX_MSG_LEN, "Message no. %d", i);

cout << "Writing message: \"" << msg->value << "\"" << endl;
status = talker->write(*msg, userHandle);

QString s=  QString::number(msg->value, 'f',8);
wSend->setText(s);
}
```

**fastsender.h**

```
class FastSender : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit FastSender(QObject *parent = 0);
FastSender(QLabel *x, QObject *parent = 0);
~FastSender();
signals:

private:
QTimer* dataTimer;
QLabel *wSend;
DDS::DomainParticipantFactory_var       dpf;

DDS::DomainParticipant_var              parentDP;
DDS::Topic_var                          signalTopic;
DDS::DataReader_var                     parentReader;
DDS::DataWriter_var                     parentWriter;
fw::signalSeq_var                       msgSeq;
char  *                                 signalTypeName;
fw::signalDataWriter_var                talker;
fw::signal                              *msg;
DDS::InstanceHandle_t                   userHandle;
DDS::Publisher_var                      fwPublisher;
int                                     alpa;
QPushButton                             *emergency;
QDialogButtonBox                        *buttonBox;

public slots:

int walk();
int hello();
void startsending();
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
fwdds = new FastWanDDS(ui->label);//receiving values are displayed in label
fwdds1 = new FastSender(ui->label_2);//Sending values are displayed in label_2
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
QTimer* timer;
int counter;
FastWanDDS *fwdds;
FastSender *fwdds1;
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Note: Only snippets of the code presented

Comment: I do not understand what is your question. Is the text in the QLabel not displayed? Note: `repaint()` is called once after MainWindow constructor returns. This is most likely before `walk()` is invoked. Thus  I guess for an update-problem. Just try to resize/move your app and see if the repaint paints the new value. (If so, you can use `wSend->update()` to update Label in `walk()`)

Comment: @BernhardHeinrich Text is being displayed, when I run the executable. Now I want the window to open and wait for my click on the push button to set the text. I want to add a push button after all

Comment: Please let me know if some more details are to be added to this

Comment: @AkhilChandraMaganti please award me the bounty if my answer worked for you. Otherwise, let me know if you have another question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: Hi Akhil, sorry I still don't unterstand the problem.... do you want to add the "Emergency" button to the MainLayout? - To add to the MainWindow you should replace the line `QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;` by the real mainLayout. (Use FastSender's constructor parameter `parent` whith `this`,  cast `parent` to QMainWindow* and us `QMainWindow::centralWidget()->layout()` ). Or, slightly simple: Add the emergency-button to the ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work this way. Does this work for you?

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "fastsender.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("unchanged");
    FastSender* fs = new FastSender(label);
    setCentralWidget(fs);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

**fastsender.h**

```
#ifndef FASTSENDER_H
#define FASTSENDER_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class FastSender : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FastSender(QLabel* label, QWidget* parent = 0)
        : QWidget(parent)
        , _label(label)
        , _timer(new QTimer)
        , _emergency(new QPushButton(tr("Emergency")))
        , _bbox(new QDialogButtonBox)
    {
        _bbox->addButton(_emergency, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);

        QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(_label);
        layout->addWidget(_bbox);

        setLayout(layout);

        connect(_emergency, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(startsending()));
        connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(walk()));
    }

public slots:
    void startsending()
    {
        _emergency->setEnabled(false);
        _timer->start(100);
    }

    int walk()
    {
        _label->setText("changed");
        _emergency->setEnabled(true);
    }

private:
    QLabel* _label;
    QTimer* _timer;
    QPushButton* _emergency;
    QDialogButtonBox* _bbox;
};

#endif // FASTSENDER_H
```